# Idea Vim bind go file (RubyMine)

Tags: ruby, rubymine, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-hub

How can I bind `gf` in idea vim (it should behaves like in vim). Same thing with `gv` (go view), `gm` (go model), etc.

Thank you for answers